# K-Means Algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, k-means

Struggling with getting a mathematical proof for K-means. Can someone help ?

Let D(d) be the average distance to centroids in K-means with k centroids . If we denote D*(k) as the average distance of an optimal clustering. Provide mathematical prove that D*(k+1) <= D*(k) . Can we prove D(k+1) <= D(k) with any clustering? Why?

Answer (score 2):

A given point $x$ belongs to the closest centroid $K(x)$. This by definition means that $x$ is further away from all other centroids not $K(x)$.

By adding a new centroid $K’$, $x$ will belong to it only if $|x-K’|\leq |x-K(x)|$. Thus, by writing down the definition of $D$, your result follows. Note that equality is achieved by placing the new centroid on top of an existing centroid.

Comment: Thanks. Can we prove D(k+1) <= D(k) with any clustering? Why? . I believe this may not be true for clustering algorithm where distance measure is not used as an objective function.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. What's your objective function if it's not the distance to the closest cluster?

Comment: I was wrong . Actually question also asks that "Can we prove D(k+1) <= D(k) with any clustering? Why?" I believe it means for any other clustering except optimal K-Means Clustering.  appreciate your thoughts